# Segmentation Fault/Out of Range on accessing a 2D vector array

Tags: c++, vector, char, 2d

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

        int m, n;
        cin>>m>>n;
        vector <vector<char>> mine(n);

    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        vector<char> row;
        for( int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        {
            char x;
            cin>>x;
            row.push_back(x);
        }
    }

  cout<<mine.at(0).at(0)<<endl;
  cout<<mine.at(-1).at(-1)<<endl;
  cout<<mine.at(3).at(3)<<endl;

}
```

My code was giving me segmentation fault on the line when I had used mine[0][0] instead of using at member function.

> cout<<mine.at(0).at(0)<<endl;

Now its giving me

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

As to why I am trying to access -1 index, I just wanted to check if the vector will ignore it. Though I don't know why it is having problems accessing the 0th index.

Comment: Your rows are never writen into mine.

Comment: You probably want a `vector<vector<char>> mine(m, vector<char>(n))`, declare `row` as `auto& row = mine[i]`, use `j` as index for your inner loop, and set `row[j] = x;` instead of pushing back.

Comment: How many `vector<char>` did you `mine.push_back` before accessing `at(0)`?

Comment: add `std::cout << mine.size() << "\n";` to see how many elements `mine` has

Comment: @rturrado    
```for( int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        auto& row = mine[i];

        for( int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
        {
            char x;
            cin>>x;
            row[j] = x;
        }
    }``` Now its having issue taking input, basically it doesn't work. Most probably I was unable to understand your steps.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see... 0 but even when I fixed the code with mine.push_back(row) it didn't work and still getting the same error.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Hello there nice to meet you again... I think it skipping over the line mine.size() but I see that I didn't push_back() row before. but even when I did, the program didn't give any output on mine.size() and still the same of out of range error.

Comment: @GuruRandapa In that case, you need to show that code (possibly in a new question) since the question you've asked does not describe the question well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- When you create your `mine` vector, it just contains `n` empty `vector<char>`.
- You then create a `row` vector within each iteration of the outer `for` loop. But that vector is not connected at all with the `mine` vector. Furthermore, that `row` vector gets destroyed at the end of every loop of the outer `for` loop.
- When you print out the contents of `mine`, `mine` contains `n` empty vectors.

  - `mine.at(0)` will give you the first empty vector (if `n >= 1`), but `mine.at(0).at(0)` will fail with an out of range exception because there's nothing within that first empty vector.
  - **`-1` index is not ignored.** If you have a look at the `at` method reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), you'll see that it receives a `std::size_t`, an unsigned integer. So integer `-1` is actually converted to a very large unsigned integer index. Check error message here: https://godbolt.org/z/xxfGhP7zq
  - `mine.at(3)` may fail if `n < 3` because you are trying to access the fourth empty vector at `mine`. If that doesn't fail, `mine.at(3).at(3)` will fail for the same reason as `mine.at(0).at(0)`. Check error message here: https://godbolt.org/z/csz6TrYf4

The code below addresses those problems: https://godbolt.org/z/a63GrW8Tx

- It creates a `mine` vector of `m` `vector<char>`s of size `n`, that is, with space for `n` chars each.
- Within the outer `for` loop, it gets a reference to `mine[i]`, the current `vector<char>`.
- And then it fills that vector accessing each `char` with `row[j]`. Since we are working on a reference to a vector in `mine`, we are modifying `mine`.
- I think using different names for the indices is clearer.
- I've commented out the out of range accesses. If you want to avoid them, you should check your indices against the vector sizes. Or just treat the exceptions.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>

  int main()
  {
      int m;
      int n;
      std::cin >> m >> n;
      std::vector<std::vector<char>> mine(m, std::vector<char>(n));

      for (int i{0}; i < m; i++)
      {
          auto& row = mine[i];
          for (int j{0}; j < n ; j++)
          {
              char x;
              std::cin >> x;
              row[j] = x;
          }
      }

      std::cout << mine.at(0).at(0) << "\n";
      //std::cout << mine.at(-1).at(-1) << "\n";  // out of range exception
      if (-1 < mine.size() and -1 < mine.at(-1).size())
      {
          std::cout << mine.at(-1).at(-1) << "\n";
      }
      //std::cout << mine.at(3).at(3) << "\n";  // out of range exception
      try
      {
          std::cout << mine.at(3).at(3) << "\n";
      }
      catch (const std::out_of_range& ex)
      {
          std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank You for taking so much of your time and giving such precious input.

Comment: @GuruRandapa My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

`cout<<mine.at(0).at(0)<<endl;` tries to access the first element of the first `vector<char>` in `mine`, but the first `vector<char>` does not contain any elements. That's why you get the segmentation fault when trying to access that element with `operator[]` or an [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception when trying to access that element with the `at()` method.

Comment: "_but the first `vector<char>` does not contain any elements_" - There _is no_ first `vector<char>`. The segmentation fault may happen when trying to access the first `vector<char>` - not the first element in the first `vector<char>`

Comment: Even when I try to access the code with ```mine.push_back(row);``` it gives me the same out of range error.

Comment: @GuruRandapa That is because you _assume_ that there _is_ a `vector<char>` in `mine` - but there is not.

Comment: @GuruRandapa What is the value of m and n? The variable mine will only have a first vector<char> element, if n is greater than zero. I assume `mine.push_back(row)` is only executed in your code if n is greater than zero, too. Otherwise, you get a segmentation fault or out_of_range exception since to try to access the first element of mine, but there is no first element.